# 64-bit PyOpenGL not able to use single buffer?

Tags: python, opengl, 64-bit, framebuffer

I recently upgraded to a 64-bit machine, and installed PyOpenGL 64 bit.  I'm using the 3.1.0a1 version of PyOpenGL, with Python 2.7.6.  My old code has stopped working in single buffer mode.  I've also tried PyOpenGL 3.0.2, and it doesn't make a difference.  So this code here:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def display():
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glFlush()

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE)
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500)
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100)
glutCreateWindow ("OpenGL Window")
glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutMainLoop()
```

Produces the window, but never renders anything inside of it.

On the other hand, this code works fine, with a nice red box showing up:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def display():
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE)
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500)
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100)
glutCreateWindow ("OpenGL Window")
glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutMainLoop()
```

Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: Did your "upgrade to a 64-bit machine" include a change in Operating System? Windows Vista/7/8 use composition, which does not work with single-buffered rendering - you can disable this in Vista/7 but it is mandatory in 8. There is no real reason to use single-buffered rendering these days anyway, the color buffer is a very small fraction of VRAM in modern software.

Comment: It's the same OS, Win7, though of course 64bit rather than 32.  Thanks for the tip on composition, but I disabled it, and even with it disabled and the system rebooted, it still doesn't work, so I don't think that it.  It was good to be aware of though.